# In XCode, where can I find a list of Operators, Global Functions, Global Constants, Special Types, Statements, Keywords, & Directives?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

A lot of other languages have good documentation for their language, but I see various implementations and would just like to see some documentation explaining things like those listed in the Title.

One great example I've used in the past (not the language itself, but the documentation) is from AS3: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html

Anything out there that I can use that is similar or just as good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_operators.htm

Thanks to @ichibod

Answer (score 1):

Since Objective C is an expansion of C, I suggest the C 'bible' from Kernichan and Ritchie.

[http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)

Comment: I was looking for something perhaps written in the last few years. Not saying a book written in 1988 is bad, but considering that's over 25 years ago, it'd be nice if there was something a little more relevant.

Comment: I believe the first edition is from 1969. Even older :-)    But you must remember that the content in it is still 100% valid. The book is well written and can be studied well.